# object search optimization in memory

Tags: java, android, search, optimization, collections

I have an ArrayList of `MyObjects`. The `MyObjects` class has more than 10  properties, but  I need to search only from 4 properties. The user will press a button and is able to select values for `property1`. 
Lets say the user will select `property1Value1`, `property1Value2` and `property1Value4`, than he will press a button and will make a selection for `property2` values: `property2Value1`, `property2Value5`, property2Value7 and so on.  Those are the filter1 and filter2. 
The `property2Value2`, `property2Value3`  and `property2Value4` is not visible to user because he filtered out with the filter1. Is like doing a search before he enter to a new filter screen. 
I  need to store somewhere what has he selected at each filter because when he navigate back I must show to him the selected values.

I think easier to understand with pictures, since similar in implemented at ebay:

No filters at beginning: user able to select all values for each property:
[image: no filters]

The user selected "Tablet" for type property. - a search is done and some property values aren't visible anymore:

[image: tablet]

The second filter value is selected:

[image: tabtype]

Pressing ( automatically) the search  I should do something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyObjects WHERE
( (property1  = property1Value1) || (property1  = property1Value2) || (property1  = property1Value4) )
AND
(  (property2 = property2Value1) ||  (property2 = property2Value5) )
```

Since I have the objects in memory I don't think is a good idea to make an sqlLite3 database, write out than select. At iOS implementation I did very complex caching algorithm. Caching the filter values separated. A loooooot of auxiliary index holders(min 20), because for each filter I  need some extra to do, not mentioned here and the data only once are stored.

I am scared to rewrite that algorithm to Android, what is at iOS, must be something easy.

**Edit**:
Basically I  need to rewrite that SQL search  in Java object searching.

**Edit2**:
Based on answer with Multimap.

The `Multimap` is not better than a `HashMap<String, <ArrarList<Integer>>`
where the key is the value of property  (`property2Value3`) and the value is a list of index to my `ArrayList<MyObjects>` (1,2,3,4,5...100)

Need to build up at each filter, each filter value the `HashMap<String, <ArrarList<Integer>>` and than exactly there I am, where the iOS...maybe with a few auxiliary collections less.

Any idea?

Comment: A `Multimap` *is* better than a map to an ID field if you're keeping the objects in memory already; you don't have the wrapper-class overhead, you don't have to manually look up the objects, and you can directly perform `Collection` operations. A `Multimap` *is* almost exactly equivalent to a `Map<Key,Set<Value>>`, with some extra convenience methods.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is basically indexing. A similar approach to what you describe is perfectly manageable in Java, it just takes the same careful coding it would in Objective C.

You haven't specified much about questions like whether multiple items are allowed to have the same values in their fields, so I'll presume they are. In that case, here's how I'd start:

- Use Guava's [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), probably `HashMultimap`, where the key is the property being index and each object being indexed gets `put` into the map under that key.
- When you're trying to search on multiple fields, call `multimap.get(property)` to get a `Collection` of all of the objects that match that property and keep only the objects that match all the properties:

  ```
  Set<Item> items = new Set<Items>(typeMultimap.get("tablet"));
  items.retainAll(productLineMultimap.get("Galaxy Tab"));
  // your results are now in "items"
  ```
- If your property list is stable, write a wrapper `Indexer` class that has fields for all of the `Multimap`s and ensures that objects are inserted into and removed from all of the property indexes, and maybe has convenience wrappers for the map getters.

Comment: +1 thanks, I will check the Multimap, never used before. Edited the question to be more clear: I  need to rewrite that SQL to search in Collection. Exactly how ebay do with sql

Comment: what do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 0):

How it executes the MYSQL that SQL behind of scene? - At a MyISAM table has a file, where he has the data, at other file the id positions.

SELECT * FROM mytable will put all IDs to the result set, because there is no filter.
Because is the * will copy all fields to id. This is equivalent with:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
for(int i=0; i < listMyObjects.size(); i++){
    if(true == true){// SELECT * FROM has a hidden WHERE 1, which is always true
      result.add(listMyObjects.get(i));
    }
}
```

in case of filter it should have a list of filters:

```
ArrayList<String> filterByProperty1 = new ArrayList<String> ();
```

at filter interface I will add some Strings `property1Value1`, `property1Value2`.... The search algorithm it will be:

```
    ArrayList<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    for(int i=0; i < listMyObjects.size(); i++){
          MyObject curMyObject = listMyObjects.get(i);
          // lets see if bypass the filter, if filter exists  
          boolean property1Allow = false;
          boolean property2Allow = false;
          if(filterByProperty1.size() > 0){
              String theCurProperty1Value = curMyObject.getProperty1();
               if(filterByProperty1.contains(theCurPropertyValue)){
                   property1Allow = true;
               }
           }
           else{// no filter by property1: allowed to add to result
               property1Allow = true;
           }

          // do the same with property2,3,4, lazzy to write it

           if(property1Allow && property2Allow){
              result.add(theCurPropertyValue);
           }
        }
    }
```

Not sure if this is a lot slower, but I least I have escaped from tenth / hundred of auxiliary collections, indexes. After this I will make the extra stuff required and is done

Comment: This looks like a whole lot of error-prone effort for an unproven performance benefit. I suggest trying a lot simpler filtering mechanism and then only trying something by hand if you can point to exactly where the slowdown is.